# Use javascript variable as a value of $regex in MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to pass arguments into a mongo query - if I type the literal, it works fine, however, when I try to replace the literal with the variable (argument), it fails

imagine a data set with "things"

```
{"thing": {"name":"book","label":"Bobs"}}
{"thing": {"name":"blanket","label":"Bobs"},
{"thing": {"name":"books","label":"Jills"},
{"thing": {"name":"blankets","label":"Jills"},
```

I have a method to find "Book" "book" "Books" "books" or "blankets"

If I do this with the literal 'Book' - it works

```
function( name, callback ) {
    Catalog
        .find({ 'thing.name': {"$regex": /Book/, "$options": "i" }})
        .exec(callback);
}
```

However - I want the argument 'name' to be used.

```
function( name, callback ) {
    Catalog
        .find({ 'thing.name': {"$regex": /name/, "$options": "i" } })
        .exec(callback);
}
```

But this doesn't work, it appears to be looking for the literal 'name' not the passed in value. how to i escape this?

Answer (score 2):

Could be done like this:-

```js
function( name, callback ) {

    Catalog
        .find({ "thing.name": { $regex: name, $options: "i" }})
        .exec(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of  `RegExp` class. It also allows you to remove `$options` property from the query, like below:

```
function( name, callback ) {

    var regexName = new RegExp(name, "i");
    Catalog
        .find({ 'thing.name': { "$regex": regexName } })
        .exec(callback);

}
```