# How to use request.query inside of regex

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express

I have this search controller and I want to set it up to check every letter in search input but I don't know how to do it with regex.

```
module.exports.search = (req, res, next) => {
  Character.find({
    $or: [
      { firstName: req.query.search },
      { lastName: req.query.search }
    ]
  })
    .then(characters => {
      res.status(200).send(characters);
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

Also, I have tried with

```
{ firstName: /req.query.search/ }
```

, but it doesn't work. Any help would be great.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270331/use-javascript-variable-as-a-value-of-regex-in-mongodb-query and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728043/mongo-query-with-regex-in-node-js-operating-on-a-variable

Comment: are you getting req.query.search or not ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena I am not getting anything when I use regex. req.query.search works perfectly fine without it, but I need to check all letters from the query, not just full string. I hope I explained it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I needed to create function to place the whole regex, and then to pass req.query to it inside of controller

```
module.exports.search = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), "gi");

    Character.find({
      $or: [{ firstName: regex }, { lastName: regex }]
    })
      .then(characters => {
        res.status(200).send(characters);
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
};

function escapeRegex(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```